# C# - Failed to convert parameter value from a RuntimeMethodInfo to a String

Tags: c#, string

Here is the code:

```
internal static void UpdateErrorLogTable(string type, string location, string method, Exception _error, string ftpDirectory, string remoteName, string localName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection databaseConnection = GetDatabaseConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = GetSqlCommand("ins_error_log", databaseConnection))
                {
                    SqlParameter log_date = cmd.Parameters.Add("@log_date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    SqlParameter exception_type = cmd.Parameters.Add("@exception_type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter class_name = cmd.Parameters.Add("@class_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter method_name = cmd.Parameters.Add("@method_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter error_msg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@error_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter stack_trace_msg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@stack_trace_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter target_site_msg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@target_site_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter ftp_directory = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ftp_directory", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter ftp_name = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ftp_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter ftp_path = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ftp_path", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter inner_exception_msg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@inner_exception_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar);

                    log_date.Value = m_todaysDate;
                    exception_type.Value = type;
                    class_name.Value = location;
                    method_name.Value = method;
                    error_msg.Value = _error.Message;
                    stack_trace_msg.Value = _error.StackTrace;
                    target_site_msg.Value = _error.TargetSite;
                    ftp_directory.Value = ftp_directory;
                    ftp_name.Value = remoteName;
                    ftp_path.Value = localName;
                    inner_exception_msg.Value = _error.InnerException;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }  // using databaseConnection
        } //end of TRY statement
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            logFile.SendToLog("SqlException", "Logs\\LogsDataAccess.cs", "UpdateErrorLogTable()", e);
        } //end of SqlException CATCH statement
    } //end of method UpdateErrorLogTable
```

The error I get is an InvalidCastException but it happens when attempting to execute

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The part I can't figure out is why am I getting an InvalidCastException here and not at one of the points above where I'm assigning values.  I stepped through the code in Debug line-by-line of this and it only gets the error when attempting to execute the code at that one line.

I performed a Google search for

> Failed to convert parameter value from a RuntimeMethodInfo to a String

but no hits.  So I searched for

> convert from RuntimeMethodInfo to String

and still no luck.

To help you understand the code a little better, the statement

```
GetSqlCommand("ins_error_log", databaseConnection)
```

basically goes out and recognizes the info in quotes is a Stored Procedure and not a query string.

All this code above has been used throughout the application (written by someone else) and all I did was copy it and make the necessary modifications to the stored procedure name, the SQL parameters, and the values inserted.

I appreciate all your help!

*Note: I tried setting the TAG for this question as "RuntimeMethodInfo" but it wouldn't let me because I have less than a 1500 reputation.  Maybe someone else can do it for me or give me the permissions to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this line:

```
target_site_msg.Value = _error.TargetSite;
```

`Exception.TargetSite` is a MethodBase, not a string. Try changing to:

```
target_site_msg.Value = _error.TargetSite.Name;
```

Comment: Sweet, let me plug this in and I will let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Well this didn't give me the value I was wanting but it did stop the error.  So I will give you credit for the fix.  I kept playing with the code and decided that if all parameters that are passed in are String datatypes (instead of passing the Exception datatype) that this prevents any errors.  Not the work around I was hoping for but sometimes it seems that you got to "duct tape" a problem.

Comment: Well I couldn't tell what you were after in your code, so I just picked something :) Glad that it pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if this is your problem, but it's not going to help:

```
inner_exception_msg.Value = _error.InnerException;
```

I think you want:

```
inner_exception_msg.Value = _error.InnerException.Message;
```

Comment: I will try that out and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Although this should have allowed the String value of InnerException to pass, I still kept getting a InvalidCast error.  A different one after I applied the change above, but still an error.  I even tried ToString() but still no fix.  It seems that I will just have to pass all my parameters as String datatypes and not the Exception datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue()`, along with the `inner_exception_msg` param needing to be a string rather than an object. [`InnerException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) is an `Exception` object, but you'll need to supply a string.

Perhaps `.Message` is good enough.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log_date", m_todaysDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exception_type", type);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class_name", location);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@method_name", method);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@error_msg", _error.Message);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stack_trace_msg", _error.StackTrace);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target_site_msg", _error.TargetSite);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ftp_directory", ftp_directory);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ftp_name", remoteName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ftp_path", localName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inner_exception_msg", _error.InnerException.Message);
```

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way but I'm curious as to why I should be using AddWithValue versus the way I had it?  Wouldn't either do the same it is just your way has less lines of code?  Again, just curious why you suggested that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Invader no problem, no offense taken! My thought was that this 11 lines of code is more readable and maintainable than 22 lines. It also expresses your intent: setup a parameter with a value. There's a developer maintaining this code after you've left and gone; if that were me, I'd be pleased to look at just the right amount of code.

Comment: Good point, and I'm glad I didn't just skip over this.  I went back to implement your suggested changes and noticed something that was creating all my problems.  I had the statement "SqlParameter <name> =" before all my "cmd.Parameters.Add" statements; your suggested code above did not.  Once I took that away there were no more casting problems because it was no longer trying to store the value into a SqlParameter datatype.  After I removed "SqlParameter <name> =" from all the code, then I was able to use .ToString() and it worked successfully!